# Spring Batch two Steps with one Decider

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-batch

I'm having following job:

```
@Bean
fun createCsvJob(
    jobs: JobBuilderFactory,
    validateCsvHeaderStep: Step,
    processCsvStep: Step,
    moveCsvStep: Step,
    markCsvAsFailedStep: Step,
    moveFailedCsvStep: Step
) = jobs.get(PROCESS_CSV_JOB)
    .start(validateCsvHeaderStep)
    .next(processCsvStep)
    .on("*").to(decider())
    .from(decider()).on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode).to(moveCsvStep)
    .from(decider()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.exitCode).to(markCsvAsFailedStep).next(moveFailedCsvStep)
    .build()
    .build()!!
```

There are two steps that can fail `validateCsvHeaderStep` and `processCsvStep`. I would like to have a flow when error in processing will go to `markCsvAsFailedStep` and `moveFailedCsvStep`, but when everything works fine it should go to `moveCsvStep`.

Currently if `validateCsvHeaderStep` fails, the whole job fails.

When I try to add decider like this:

```
    .start(validateCsvHeaderStep)
    .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.exitCode).to(decider())
    .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode).to(processCsvStep)
    .on("*").to(decider())
    .from(decider()).on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode).to(moveCsvStep)
    .from(decider()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.exitCode).to(markCsvAsFailedStep).next(moveFailedCsvStep)
```

I'm getting:

`Next state not found in flow=myJob for state=myJob.validateCsvStep with exit status=COMPLETED`

Is there a way to achieve error handling for both steps without duplicating logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the flow starting from `validateCsvHeaderStep` to the decider on `COMPLETED` like follows:

```
.start(validateCsvHeaderStep)
.on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode).to(processCsvStep)
.from(validateCsvHeaderStep)on("*").to(decider())
```

> here are two steps that can fail validateCsvHeaderStep and processCsvStep. I would like to have a flow when error in processing will go to markCsvAsFailedStep and moveFailedCsvStep, but when everything works fine it should go to moveCsvStep.

Here is an example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step validateCsvHeaderStep() {
        return steps.get("validateCsvHeaderStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("validateCsvHeaderStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step processCsvStep() {
        return steps.get("processCsvStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("processCsvStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step markCsvAsFailedStep() {
        return steps.get("markCsvAsFailedStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("markCsvAsFailedStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step moveFailedCsvStep() {
        return steps.get("moveFailedCsvStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("moveFailedCsvStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step moveCsvStep() {
        return steps.get("moveCsvStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("moveCsvStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {

        return jobs.get("job")
                .flow(validateCsvHeaderStep())
                    .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(markCsvAsFailedStep())
                    .from(validateCsvHeaderStep()).on("*").to(processCsvStep())

                    .from(processCsvStep()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(markCsvAsFailedStep())
                    .from(processCsvStep()).on("*").to(moveCsvStep())

                    .from(markCsvAsFailedStep()).on("*").to(moveFailedCsvStep())

                    .from(moveFailedCsvStep()).end()
                    .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

it prints:

```
validateCsvHeaderStep
processCsvStep
moveCsvStep
```

If for example `validateCsvHeaderStep` fails:

```
    @Bean
    public Step validateCsvHeaderStep() {
        return steps.get("validateCsvHeaderStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("validateCsvHeaderStep");
                    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
```

It prints:

```
validateCsvHeaderStep
markCsvAsFailedStep
moveFailedCsvStep
```

If `processCsvStep` fails:

```
    @Bean
    public Step processCsvStep() {
        return steps.get("processCsvStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("processCsvStep");
                    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
```

it prints:

```
validateCsvHeaderStep
processCsvStep
markCsvAsFailedStep
moveFailedCsvStep
```

Hope this helps.